# How one client can know about presence of another client in mqtt

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

It is possible to get notify when another client was connected to same topic which is subscribed by same topic in mqtt.

ex: a client subscribed to : `app/id` another client also subscribed to `app/id` then both clients will get a message about number of clients subscribed to this particular topic.

if it is possible then please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a pub/sub architecture is to unlink the producer of information (publisher) from the consumer (subscriber). Producers just publish to a topic and the broker deals with routing that message to any consumers that may have a matching topic pattern subscription.

There is no way to count how many clients may receive a given message at any particular time for the following reasons:

1. A subscriber may be using a wildcard topic pattern that happens to match the topic of the published message.
2. A subscriber may have a persistent session with a matching topic pattern but if currently off line and will receive the queued message when it next connects
3. With shared subscriptions there could be any number of clients pooled together subscribed to a given topic pattern, but only one of them will receive any given message as they are load balanced round the group.

There is no guarantee that there are ever any subscribers, in the same way there is no end to end delivery guarantee only between a single client and the broker.

In a sensibly implemented broker, subscription topic pattern matches are only evaluated when a new message is published, so the best you could ever get is how many clients the last message with a given topic was delivered to, as there is no efficient way to calculate the number in advance.

In the same way as your last question about topics, if you think knowing this is required then you need to rethink your design or your use of MQTT.

Comment: Thanks again Bro, These information are very helpful for me to decide to use MQTT or not on my device.